# How to clean outside of windows and doors

Tags: cleaning, home

It has been a long time since I shifted to our new house and I noticed that a lot of dirt and webs has converted our main door and windows. I am looking to clean them up but I don't think a microfibre cloth will be helpful as it might get dusty and catch web in it, making it quickly useless.

What is the best way to get clean outside doors/windows or main entrance wall from web and dust?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen people wrap an old towel around the head of a broom. Using that to clean off dust and webs seems very effective! The broom head is firm and wide yet somewhat flexible, and the towel easily brushes away dust and webs.

Some tips:

- After you wrap the towel around the head of the broom, use a strong clip (like a binder clip or bulldog clip) to secure the towel in place.
- When the towel starts to get dusty or full of webs, take it off and replace it with a fresh, new towel.
- Don't wet the towel. That will tend to cause dust to streak, and that's hard to hide later.

Comment: Oh, look! A diamond! Congratulations Brett.

Comment: Oh, that's what that is! Thanks for pointing that out, @Stan!

Answer (score 3):

**Window Cleaning LifeHack**

When cleaning windows (without a glass squeegee) using paper towels, cloths, or newspaper, always wipe in the same direction for the outside window surface and in a cross-wise direction on the inside.

For example: Use up-and-down for the inside window surfaces and side-to-side for the outside surface. You could also swap the directions but the idea is to be consistent when cleaning your windows.

Why? It will help to immediately **identify which side of the window has any remaining streaks** when the light changes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a lifehack for this. Use a corner broom to remove the large debris:

[image]

and then a rough, wet cloth (no need for microfiber cloth either) to finish off.

Comment: I'm amazed this exists; I don't think I've ever struggled getting a normal rectangular broom into a corner!